# Check excel row columns

Tags: c#, datatable

Work on C#.I need to read excel file then need to check all rows datas.To solve this problem i do the follow steps

```
1)Read the excel file.
2)put the excel file information in DataTable.

Order   Produ   price     quan   Discount
10248   11      14.0000   12     0
10248   42      9.8000    10     0
10248   72      34.8000   5      0
10249   14      18.6000   9      0
10249   51      42.4000   40     0
```

suppose above is in my **excel format**.i need to read it. I have done steps 1 and 2.I need help to check the excel row values, suppose one row of my excel Discount column contain ProductName.Than what to do?How can i check this type of errors and how to avoid this type of error.I use bellow syntax to read the excel file

```
OpenFileDialog oOpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (oOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    txtFilePath.Text = oOpenFileDialog.FileName;
}
FileStream stream = File.Open(txtFilePath.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);


IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
```

Comment: Technically, this comes under a logical error which means you will probably have to manually check each value unless there is some difference such as productname can only be alphanumeric and discount can only be numeric, or even if discount is within some range of numbers and the productname is in a different range. Then you can have some automated testing but otherwise I would think manually each one

Comment: nEm thanks for reply.but this process does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be using OLEDB provider for Excel. You don't need excel to be installed on the server as well. 
In this option also you end up with dataset, if you iterate over the rows of the retrieved tables, and then check for the type of the data read, you should be able to figure out if the data read is in right format.
TryParse kind of functions might be of help.

Prasad Pimparkar

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (datarow item in DataTable.Rows)
    {
```

bellow syntax gives the cell data type.
   Now check this type with cxcel row cell.If Type not match then this cell content is not invalid.
        suppose you rows first column is Int .if one cell contain datatype string ,then what your cell content is invalid

```
 //item[index].GetType()
}
```